# Gstreamer-sharp 1.16 Playbin "Could not query current duration."

Tags: c#, .net, gstreamer, video-processing, gstreamer-sharp

I am trying to run C# sample [BasicTutorial4.cs](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/-/blob/1.16.0/samples/BasicTutorial4.cs) from [Gstreamer-sharp's 1.16](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/-/tree/1.16.0) own source, Video plays fine, but I can't get video duration [it always files with error: "Seeking DISABLED for this stream."](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/-/blob/1.16.0/samples/BasicTutorial4.cs#L116-122)

I tried different file, other than default bick buck bunny video but result is the same.

I have installed [gstreamer-1.0-mingw-x86_64-1.16.2](http://%20gstreamer-1.0-mingw-x86_64-1.16.2.), in windows 10.

Is this bug in Gstreamer framework or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GStreamer for years, but I would suggest having a look at the [Discoverer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/gstreamer-tools.html?gi-language=c#gstdiscoverer10).  Some file formats are not seekable.